# Writing a Macro that duplicates a specific row into the number of rows inserted

Tags: vba, excel, row

I am trying to write a macro that inserts the number of rows I specify under a row that I have selected. Each of those newly inserted rows need to duplicate a row of formulas already created in the workbook (Row 2). I can't seem to figure out how to get the macro to paste that row of formulas into each of the newly created rows. I am extremely new to macros and would appreciate any help! Here is what I have (and it works for creating the # of rows, but only pastes Row 2 into the last row created):

```
Sub InsertSessions
Dim Rng as long
Dim k as long
Dim rRange as Range

Set rRange = Selection

ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select

Rng = InputBox("Enter number of sessions:.")
For k = 1 To Rng
Rows(rRange.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown, _
           CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Rows(2).Copy Destination:= Rows(rRange.Row)
End Sub
```

If possible, I would also like to know how to have the macro do the following 2 things:

1. create one less row then indicated in the selection (i.e. If I enter 4 sessions, I would like only 3 rows to be created
2. Is there a way for the first row created to include on set of formulas (copied from say "Row 2") and all subsequent rows to be copied from say "Row 3" (i.e. if I entered 4 sessions, the first row would duplicate Row 2 and the next 2 inserted rows would duplicate Row 3)

THANKS!!!

Comment: 1) do you have absolute references (with `$` sign) in formulas or relative? 2) if relative, do you need to paste exact formulas in new row, or adjusted (when you formula contains, say `=A1`, after pasting it in new row it would be adjusted to, say `=D1`)?

Comment: Relative - adjusted to the row they are pasted in

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub InsertSessions()
Dim Rng As Long
Dim k As Long
Dim rRange As Range

Set rRange = Selection

ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select

Rng = InputBox("Enter number of sessions:.")
For k = 1 To Rng
Rows(rRange.Row).Insert Shift:=xlDown, _
           CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Call rRange.Copy(Range(Cells(rRange.Row - 1, rRange.Column), Cells(rRange.Row - 1, rRange.Column)))


Next k
End Sub
```

Comment: unfortunately, it gave me the same results - the requested number of rows with the formulas only populating the last row

Comment: that is weird. This is what i'm doing. I have a formula in cells A1 to A10. I select cells A5 then i run the macro. Lets say I enter 3. Then I get A1 to A13 with the same forumal. Is this not what you are trying to do?

Comment: So, ideally I would like my formulas to live in cells A1 - H1. When I run the macro, I would like the number of specified rows to populate below the row of the selected cell (i.e. I have selected cell E4, run the macro choose 3, and then A5-H5, A6-H6, A7-H7 are inserted with the same relative formulas as A1-H1).